# Pairing 2 Bluetooth headsets on Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez, headset

I am unable to pair 2 Bluetooth headsets with Raspberry Pi. Only one is working, the other one is kicked out, when I try to pair via Blueman.

```
dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'
Version: 4.99-2
```

Both devices are trusted. One Headset is working, but I need two of them at the same time. Does anyone have a tip where should I look?

Comment: Could try using `hcitool` command instead.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi does not allow 2 bluetooth devices to be connected at once. I believe addons by beaglebone or similar should allow you to do so however